# Know if HTTP request is from Chrome URL auto-complete?

Tags: google-chrome

We have a web application that responds to `GET /logout` and deletes your session cookies.  If you start typing any other URL that beings with `/l` into the URL bar, Chrome will auto-suggest `/logout`.  When it does this, it makes a request to `/logout` to pre-fetch the content.  The result is that the user is un-expectedly logged out.

How can my HTTP server know if a request is from this pre-fetch behavior?

What I've tried:

- Inspecting the request headers for something unique.  I do not see anything unique from the pre-fetch request.
- Using `'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store'` to tell the browser to not cache the response from `GET /logout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your logout to use POST instead of GET.