# Chrome pre-fetch causes duplicate flash message

Tags: php, google-chrome, symfony

In my Symfony 3.0.6 application, certain common routes are not available until a user's registration has been finalised. Until this has been done, I use an `AccessDeniedHandlerInterface` to redirect them to a route that prompts them to finalise it. I also use a flash message to explain what has happened:

```
/**
 * Handles an access denied failure.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param AccessDeniedException $accessDeniedException
 *
 * @return Response may return null
 */
public function handle(Request $request, AccessDeniedException $accessDeniedException)
{
    if (null === $token = $this->security->getToken()) {
        return;
    }

    if (!is_object($user = $token->getUser())) {
        return;
    }

    /** @var User $user */

    if (!$user->isFinalised()) {
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'You need to complete your registration before you can do this!');
        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('app_registration_complete'));
    }

    return;
}
```

However, a problem arises with Chrome's pre-fetch/pre-rendering service - if Chrome decides a URL is likely to be visited, it will pre-fetch it. A pre-fetch results in the flash message above being added to the user's session, so *any* subsequent page load means there are shown the message. If they do in fact go to a route they are not yet allowed to access, they see the message twice - one generated during the pre-fetch, and one generated when they actually navigated.

A similar issue is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35586472/759924), but the accepted answer (use a `POST` for logout requests) doesn't really seem like the right solution in this context. The flash message is more of an explanatory addition to a `GET` redirection, as opposed to something that changes the state of the application. Also, there are many ways a user might reach one of these disallowed routes, and it doesn't make sense to me to convert all of these to trigger a `POST`, just to get around a pre-fetch issue in certain situations.

So... how should I deal with this?

Answer (score -1):

I see one problem with your code. You should change to this:

```
if (null === $this->security->getToken()) {
    return;
}
```

I don't think this will resolve the problem though.

Comment: Hi Alvin, I'm afraid you're mistaken there - the `=` operator has a higher precedence than `===`. Run `var_dump(null === $a = null);` to see it in action.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Alex. You are right. I see from that code it might also initialize the variable $token. My mistake - sorry.